# Bootstrap datepicker and Fuel UX datepicker conflicting

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, bootstrap-datepicker, fuelux

I am trying to use the Fuel UX wizard control, along with Bootstrap. However, since I am using also Bootstrap's datepicker there seems to be a conflict involved in using the datepicker from one and the other library, since both define with $.fn.datepicker the same name for the datepicker jQuery plugin.

An obvious solution for me would be to only enable the Fuel UX controls I really need to use. The Fuel UX documentation states that this in fact can be achieved as explained here https://github.com/exacttarget/fuelux/blob/master/DETAILS.md#amd-support, however it seems that as of version 3.0 of Fuel UX the individual .js files are not included in a release anymore, so that the approach of loading a single Fuel UX control doesn't work as expected since we get a 404 response from their CDN server.

Any thoughts on how a workaround may be achieved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that only the `dist` folder is present on the CDN. If you `bower install` or `npm install`, you will have access to the `js` [folder](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/tree/master/js).

Think of the CDN as the "quick, get things working" method and [Bower](http://bower.io/)/[NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuelux) (or even git submodules) as the "optimize my project" direction.

Comment: I see. Well, I'd have to check what the best alternative would be for me since we're using webjars for dependency mgmt, which also only includes the files located in the CDN. I'm not quite sure why the single control libraries were excluded from the CDN, after all the total network load on the CDN would probably drop if these libraries would be made available for downloading from there.

Comment: What version do you need? I can add the `js` folder to the CDN for your particular version if that would help.

Comment: It would be great if you could to that! :) Would you include the js folder also to the following releases as well? This way I guess it would be picked up also by webjars and included in their realease flavor as well, but for now I  could switch to CDN in my project. Thanks!

Comment: I need to know your version. I'm just going to update that version.

Comment: 3.11.1, the last stable one. Are you going to include the single .js files in future versions too?

Comment: Uploaded to http://www.fuelcdn.com/fuelux/3.11.1/js/datepicker.js . The JS folder is really source files. If you'd like to see see the `dist` contain single controls, please submit an issue and we'll take it under consideration.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I seriously appreciate your effort. I will post an issue tomorrow as well since I strongly believe that having the single source files available in a release will be very useful for the community.